# how to use R to retain the previous id condition on another column?

Tags: r

I have a table has column ID, prd, line. I would like to revise the line definition for each ID as long as the prd is the same with previous record, then keep the line same as the column new_line in the example below.

[image]

```
new_data <- data.frame('ID'=c('123','123','123','456','456','789','789','789'),
               'prd' = c('a','a','b','b','a','c','c','d'),
               'line' = c(1,2,3,1,2,2,3,4))
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, one way using `lag` and `cumsum` would be

```
library(dplyr)

new_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_line = first(line) + cumsum(prd != lag(prd, default = first(prd))))


#  ID    prd    line new_line
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 123   a         1        1
#2 123   a         2        1
#3 123   b         3        2
#4 456   b         1        1
#5 456   a         2        2
#6 789   c         2        2
#7 789   c         3        2
#8 789   d         4        3
```

Using `data.table` `rleid` it becomes a bit shorter

```
new_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_line = first(line) + data.table::rleid(prd) - 1)
```